# Angular 2 front-end and Laravel 5* back-end

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5

I want always to use **Angular2** for my front-end and **Laravel 5*** for my back-end.

> How I could combine both of them in the same project? Am I must separate them? Or do I only combine them if I have my Laravel as an API?

**Please provide me with videos and tutorials**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to learn these separately and **then** try to combine these two, because looking at your question, you should know how to do it, if you know these two frameworks.

But yeah, there is 2 options, copy angular files to public/ folder or run two independent servers and connect these two on localhost.